# How to support input Chinese (UTF-8) in boot2docker(tiny core) /bin/sh (shell)

Tags: linux, shell, utf-8, docker, boot2docker

How to support input Chinese (UTF-8) in boot2docker(tiny core) /bin/sh (shell)

For support Chinese (UTF-8), I try:

```
su - docker -c "tce-load  -wi getlocale coreutils "
sudo  getlocale.sh ==> select en_US.UTF-8 ==> enter ==> this will generate mylocale.tce file
su - docker -c "tce-load -i mylocale  coreutils"
```

Then relogin will Chinese filename is supported now

But bin  /bin/sh shell input Chinese has issue:

[image: tinycore /bin/sh shell input Chinese issue]

Comment: ref: http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=16067.0

Comment: are you sure that /bin/sh is bash? Usually /bin/sh is required to be only a minimal shell with a lot of options missed. Sometimes a special stripped down build of bash could act as /bin/sh, but sometimes completely different beasts like `ash` or `dash` are used instead. Just check if it's not a (hard) link to some other shell and what is in fact