# Unable to see non-Latin filename in manually created host volume

Tags: docker

Host: Windows 10

Docker: 1.12.0

VirtureBox: 5.1.4

I did the following to share my host folder for docker:

1. add vbox sharefolder with:

   `C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage sharedfolder add default -name projects -hostpath d:/Documents/Projects -automount`
2. ssh to docker-machine and add file /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh as:

   `mkdir -p /d/Documents/projects`

   `mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker`projects /d/Documents/projects`
3. restart docker-machine.
4. ssh to docker-machine to see my file:

   `ls /d/Documents/projects`

   .. only filename with full latin characters showed

   `ls /c/Users/myname/Desktop`

   .. all files showd, although non-latin characters display as ?, this is no problem

How can I make my new created host volume work with non-latin filenames as the default one?

Comment: May be this problem caused by that boot2docker doesn't support Non-Latin UTF-8 very well. This question might related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783538/how-to-support-input-chinese-utf-8-in-boot2dockertiny-core-bin-sh-shell

Comment: I don't think so. Docker toolbox mount c:\Users as default host volume, every file there works fine. My question is I can't make share volume in other driver work with non-latin filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great thanks to https://github.com/ailispaw, the problem was solved by adding option iocharset to mount command:

> mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,iocharset=utf8,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker`

The issue in github is:
https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/1205#event-820392641